# Monit : monitor remote processes

Tags: monit

I want to setup a "Monit" on a centralized server to monitor the process on the remote  servers.   (In My use case, i want to restart the Storm supervisors on servers A,B,C and  Kafka brokers on servers D,E,F,G if they get shut down). I could not find an example where monit is used to monitor the remote processes. Is there any way to achieve the same using monit or any  alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I am using an Ubuntu Server 16.04, So my syntax and file location may different than yours.

I was able to open the `/etc/monit/monitrc` and input the remote server i am trying to monitor This is the syntax I used:

### Test to Check the host server remotely

`check host host.domain.name with address ip.addy.here.ip`
`start program = "ssh user@ipaddress /etc/init.d/sshd start"`
`stop program = "ssh user@ipaddress /etc/init.d/sshd stop"`
`if failed port 22 protocol ssh`
`then alert`

Of course you would have to use a user with priviledges.

Comment: Won't this test shut down the SSHD daemon on the remote server? is that wise?